# Jenkins - Copy artifacts/package with specific filter

Tags: jenkins

I have PACKAGE job which produces ZIP package depending on `Choice` parameter. Depending on the choice, package name is either archived with name MyPackageWINDOWS.ZIP or MyPackageLINUX.ZIP.

I have a DEPLOY job which should fetch *.ZIP package depending on what the Choice parameter was. Choice parameters are:
* Linux
* Windows

If i choose Linux, deploy job should copy latest package named MyPackageLINUX.ZIP
If i choose Windows, deploy job should copy latest package named MyPackageWINDOWS.ZIP

I have "Buid Selector for Copy Artifacts" and "Copy Artifacts from another project" plugins but not sure how to achieve this. Is this possible at all? Any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have `Choice Parameter` defined, to achieve what you want (using my suggestion), you will need to install the following plugins, if they already aren't:

1. [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin
2. [Conditional BuildStep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin
3. [Copy Artifact](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) plugin

There can be different ways to achieve what you want. I will mention one of them:

1. In your build job, you can create a file (lin.txt/win.txt) depending on the Choice parameter that was selected for that particular build.
2. In your deploy job, check the file that got created by the build job and copy the relevant package.

**Steps to achieve the goal using the above mentioned plugins:**

For this example, i have created two jobs (Build & Deploy). The Deploy job is a downstream job of Build job.

- In your Build job, go to `Build > Execute Windows batch command (Execute shell, if you're on *nix)`. You can refer the screenshot below for further details:

[image]

[image]

- Now in your Deploy job, go to `Build > Conditional step (single)`. Refer the screenshot below for further details:

[image]
[image]

P.S.: If you have a Master-Slave setup and if your build and deploy jobs are not tied to any slave, you can select a common location (accessible to both the jobs) where you will be creating the temporary file (lin.txt/win.txt). In the screenshot above, it can be selected using `Base directory` option. Another thing that you can change as per your settings is `Which build` option shown in the screenshot above.